# Geometry nodes - Material Selection node not working

Tags: geometry-nodes

Material Selection node not working with anything: Distribution on Points, Separated Geometr
tested on two versions of Blender 3.5 & 3.6.2

[image]

Funni thing, that I have a project in which this node works just fine

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe try setting Viewer mode to Faces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch to "link material of object to 'object data'"
[image]